# Password prompt

Tags: c, password-protection

I'm trying to write a simple password prompt.. I must admit, I found some code, but it doesn't work for my specific purpose. I'm still learning C, and this is just another step up the ladder. I'm trying to get it to where it continues on if the password is correct, and will terminate if the password is incorrect.

```
int c;
char pass[20] = "";
char *end = pass + sizeof(pass) - 1;
char *dst = pass;

printf("Enter password: ");
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && dst < end)
*dst++ = c;
*dst = '\0';  // Ensure null termination

printf("\nPass: %s\n", pass);

return 0;
```

The code seems to "lock up" at the "Enter password" prompt. Thanks for your help. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code seems to print the pass correctly over here... What do you mean by "lock up"?

Comment: Just that. It doesn't accept input.

Comment: Its working fine for me. my gcc version 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4) (GCC)

Comment: After printing "Enter password: ", `getchar` will wait until you input something. What happens when you do and press enter? Is it still "locked up"? Does the program terminate?

Comment: You mean you want it to hide the password while the user is typing it? Like erase the pw character he's currently typing with an asterisk?

Comment: The code haccks submitted is working fine for me. Thank you.

Comment: @user2990606: Good to hear that you've found a solution. But please consider to pay more attention to your problem description next time. By saying that the code "locks up", you've misled quite a bunch of people by suggesting that you cannot get any response from your console program, perhaps because of an infinite loop, when you were really just looking for a way to compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `if` statement with `strcmp` to check whether the entered password is correct or not.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    char pass[20] = "";
    char *end = pass + sizeof(pass) - 1;
    char *dst = pass;
    char admin[] = "12345";

    printf("Enter password: ");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && dst < end)
        *dst++ = c;

    *dst = '\0';  // Ensure null termination

    if(strcmp(admin, pass) == 0)
        printf("\nPass: %s\n", pass);
    else
    {
        printf("Incorrect password");
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but it seems that the string comparison is not the OP's problem; the password input is.

Comment: OP says that for him, input locks, which other people (including me) can't reproduce on their machines. Your correction concerns the logic of the program. I think the OP hasn't implemented it yet, because of the input problem.

Comment: Neither do I nor other commenters, see above. At the moment it is not clear what the OP's issue really is; we'll have to wait for more information. Could be system dependent behaviour of `stdin` together with unflushed `stdout´, who knows?

Comment: Congratulations! Looks like the title of "Clairvoyant of the Year" is already awarded on New Year's Day. I could never have guessed that "lock up" really means that the string comparison is missing.

Comment: @MOehm; Uff! Of course I given my answer by guessing what OP wanted to do : *I'm trying to get it to where it continues on if the password is correct, and will terminate if the password is incorrect.*

Comment: No offence meant. Sure, that's what the poster asked, but the last paragraph about "locking up" put me on the wrong track altogether. And, judging by other comments, not just me. Never mind. Enough time wasted on what was a very simple question.

Comment: Yes. A very simple question.

Comment: @user2990606; Yes please. Go ahead :)

Comment: The code fails to compile. disclaim.c: In function 'main':
disclaim.c:66:3: error: break statement not within loop or switch
   break;
   ^

Comment: @user2990606; Oh! That was typo. Replace `break` with `exit (0);`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, it is. But it "advances" if I don't press a key.

Comment: What do you mean by `advances`?

Comment: It continues on to the next program in the loop. I'm calling the code through a "front end" of sorts, and it goes straight to the next program automatically.

Comment: Hmmm. Then you must not use `exit`. Now try `return 0;`.

Comment: could you sho me your complete code. Post that code here: http://ideone.com/. and after compiling it, give me the link.

Comment: I tried but failed to reproduce it. Hard luck. Code I posted should work. Spite of this there are many errors in your code. What do you think `size_t file_size = ftell(fp);
  buff = malloc(file_size);` will do? This will not allocate the space do you want.

Comment: Sorry for I did't helped you much :(

Comment: OK. I got it working. The problem was the '\n', I replaced it with "13" and it works. Thanks for all of your help.